# LaterJS to run on event dates with data payload

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, laterjs

I have a dynamic list of events that contains the `timestamp`, `db row id`, `class`, `start`, `end`, and `title`.

I'm using [laterjs](/questions/tagged/laterjs) to run every 5 minutes to get the updated object list from a database. I can put the events into [laterjs](/questions/tagged/laterjs) with no problem by using the schedule array, however if I do that then i'm having trouble getting the data of the event back when [laterjs](/questions/tagged/laterjs) triggers on it so that I can update the screen with the event title that is being triggered.

```js
var newSchedule = later.parse.text('every 5 minutes');
var newTimer = later.setInterval(getNewData, newSchedule);

function getNewData() {
    /*
    do ajax and get new data, data will look something like
    $result['schedules'] = array(
        array('id' => '101', 'class' => 'incoming', 'title' => 'Goodbye', 'start' => '10:00pm', 'end' => '11:00pm'),
        array('id' => '319', 'class' => 'outgoing', 'title' => 'Welcome home', 'start' => '1:00pm', 'end' => '2:00pm')
    );
    */

    // manual test schedule
    var displayData = {
        schedules: [
            {dy: [23], h: [7], m: [40]},
            {dy: [23], h: [7], m: [41]},
            {dy: [23], h: [7], m: [42]}
        ]
    };
    var displayTimer = later.setInterval(updateDisplay, displayData);
}

function updateDisplay() {
    // when this is fired, i'm trying to obtain the data of the event from the ajax call so to update the title on the page
}
```

seems like [laterjs](/questions/tagged/laterjs) might not be the solution to this task